# AppsScript - Scanning a Google Sheets table and drop down cell to update the table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I am VERY new to apps script, and scripting in general. I am trying to create some code that will scan a google sheets table after being triggered with an image or cell link. It will then scan the table for a specific variable from a drop down list and store the co-ordinate as a variable. I then will want it to select two cells over and paste a value. This system will be used to easily update inventory levels.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is easy to accomplish with images of your data showing inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.